# Flag duplicate keys in dictionary using pylint

Tags: python, dictionary, pylint

Is there a static code analysis tool that can flag duplicate keys in a python dictionary?

Context:
I use large dictionary to capture tasks in a scheduler. If mistakenly key name for two tasks are the same then the 2nd item replaces the 1st item silently and we lose one task in the the schedule.

I was hoping if we can flag this duplicate key using code analysis (lint).

Code example:

```
d = {'a': 1,'b': 2, 'a': 3}
print(d.items())

>>dict_items([('a', 3), ('b', 2)])
```

Comment: you'd probably need to check it during runtime

Comment: in runtime 2nd key completely replaces the 1st key. there is no way to know if the 1st key existed in the original code.

Comment: I feel like we're missing some important context, can you make this into a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Maybe then instead of a dictionary it's easier to use a list of lists of two values? d = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['a', 3]]}

Comment: Or a queue would be better for the scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pylint](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/installation/index.html) has [`duplicate-key`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/duplicate-key.html). Result on your code example:

```
************* Module a
a.py:1:4: W0109: Duplicate key 'a' in dictionary (duplicate-key)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I would recommend using a priority queue.

> The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry is the one returned by sorted(list(entries))[0]). A typical pattern for entries is a tuple in the form: (priority_number, data).
> [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)